# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)

Tags: python

I made a vector of constant values. The vector is (1 row, 6colums). Then, I call the vector in another function and I want to use each element of the vector for making other calcualtions. The problem is that I get the following error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)

Why? Is there someone that can help me?
Best regards,

```
n=6
F = np.ones([1,n])  
F = F*0.4

# F: [[0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4]] 
# Other function
str=np.zeros([1,n])
for i in range(0, len(F)):
    str[i] = 1000 * F[i]

# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `F` is not a list of values, but a list of one list of values.  I can see this by the extra `[]` surrounding your values.  So when you do the calculation `str[i] = 1000 * F[i]` you are working with 2 lists.  You could try replacing that line with `str[0][i] = 1000 * F[0][i]` to access the 0th element of the outerlist (which is just the list of values) and then picking the ith value from that list.

This might not be exactly the answer you are looking for, something that can help get good answers is to post the full traceback.  Odds are you have much more to your error message than the one line `ValueError`, that extra information would be very useful posted in your questions!  You could also add the definition for whatever `Fd_ULS` is.

Comment: Hi, thansk for your valuabe answer. Fd_ULS is F, sorry I forgot to change it. Would it be pobbible to define instead F as just one list? In particular, I would to define F as a normal vector insted of modifing the sintax in the for loop ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your valuabel comment. I define F in a different way.

Comment: for i in range(0,n):
                F[i]=0.4

Comment: Numpy is often used for 2D matrices, When you passed in `[1,n]` to your function call `F = np.ones([1,n])` you are telling numpy to build a 1xn matrix with ones.  You only want a 1D array to come out, so you only need 1 argument: `F = np.ones(n)`  will give you what you are looking for.